# Hover image not centred (CSS + JS)

Tags: javascript, css, debugging

In the following solution, I can't seem to be able to centre to the screen the image appearing at hover.

How can I solve this? Is this a CSS `position` issue or can be resolved in JS?

https://jsfiddle.net/Mengolor/2wzv6tr1/1/

```
div {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    top: 250px;
    left: 100px;
}

img#image {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 99;
    max-width: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h3 {
  padding: 40px;
}

span:hover img#image {
    display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
        const { scrollTop, scrollLeft } = document.documentElement;
    $("#image").css({left:e.clientX + scrollLeft, top:e.clientY + scrollTop});
});
```

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks for the feedback. I have corrected the entry.

Comment: There is not enough code in the question itself to repo you issue. Use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? Otherwise this question is off topic for stack overflow since

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making your position attribute relative, try position:center;

```html
div {
 position: center;
 border: 1px solid gray;
 border-radius: 6px;
 width: 600px;
 height: auto;
 top: 250px;
 left: 100px;
}
```

I tested this in the JSFiddle console, and it seemed to work.

Comment: thanks for the input but this changes the page structure. What I was looking for was a solution for the image to always be centered. any ideas?

Comment: try changing your position: center attributes like position: center 6px; I haven't tested this but I hope this will help you.